# Randomly silencing part of input audio in real time

Tags: linux, audio, ffmpeg, sox, pulseaudio

My machine is running Ubuntu 20 LTS. I want to manipulate the input live audio in real-time. I have achieved pitch shifting using sox. The command being -

```
 sox -t pulseaudio default -t pulseaudio null pitch +1000
```

and then routing the audio from "Monitor of Nullsink" .

What I actually want to do is, silence randomized parts of the input audio, with a range. What I mean is, randomly mute 1-2s of the input audio.

The final goal of this project will be to write a script that manipulates my voice and makes it seems like my network is bad.

There is no restriction in method of achieving. That is we may use any language, make an extension, directly manipulate the input audio with sox, ffmpeg etc. Anything goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution by using `trim` in sox. The project can be found in

https://github.com/TathagataRoy1278/Bad_Internet_Audio_Modulator